# Is there a better solution than using session variables; should session variables really be used in Web Pages, at all?

Tags: c#, session-variables, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix (C#) to design Intranet web applications for the organization I work for.

I have made one database driven site, and am currently working on another, and for some time, I have been having some trouble with the Session variables randomly becoming null and throwing errors. So much so, that one simple Session variable was switched with the use of the server cache memory instead (which I originally thought would be more volatile, but that remains to be seen, so far...)

One question is: Is there any practical use of the Session variable, at all? If it truly is as volatile as it has seemed to be, they appear to be good for just about nothing.\

I know they are technically cookies, so I know that their data shouldn't be relied upon, but therein lies the problem. I need to send data to other pages that I "can" rely upon. This leaves out both Session variables and cookies.

I generally stay away from query strings or url data, for their blatant "plain-text" display of any sensitive information (like Social Security Numbers), with which, even SSL won't help.

The server cache memory is also volatile and is not to be relied upon.

AppState variables aren't user specific.

That leaves hidden input fields... The problem here is that, sometimes after "Post" I do Response.Redirect, and such, so C# doesn't always render a page after post (it seems).

Maybe this is just a lack of knowledge on my part, but I kind of seem cornered no matter which way I go.

Do I really have to save all page information into a separate database with every page and retrieve it with a sql query on the other page just to get reliable and not "blatantly" displayed information from one page to another with Web Pages? Still even this method would be a problem using several different users, no?

Comment: Sessions vars have their downsides but should be stable as long as the session remains alive.

Comment: One remark: session variables are not "basically cookies", they are **not** sent to the client at all. The ID of the session is the only value that is stored in a cookie, the rest stays server-side.

Comment: it depends on the implementation, but session is often cross-web front end, while caches aren't.  Caches should be primarily used for re-using something you can re-compute for performance gains because it could go away at any time (and that should be okay).  Session is, by design, more for something that can't just be re-computed.

Comment: @Hans Kesting Thank you for telling me this, I didn't know that. However, if they clear the cookies on their browser (or they otherwise fail with their session ID) isn't that just as unreliable?

Comment: @Iboshuizen How can anyone ever be sure that the session will remain alive? All anyone has to do is clear cookies and everything breaks, which if that was 'all' that it was, it wouldn't be that big of a deal, because I would just tell the users, "don't do that then!" But alas, I have one particular session variable that (only sometimes) randomly becomes null/empty.

Comment: @VoidKing The session ends when there is no useractivity within the session-timeout-window (norm 20mins) or the app gets reset (reloading web.config as example). Clearing cookies will not reset the session but breaks "the link" between client and the session.

Comment: @Iboshuizen Is there a way to increase the number of minutes before the session timeout (above or below 20mins)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET has different Session State modes:

- *InProc*, this is in-memory. Session State lives as long as the IIS Application Pool isn't recycled or the entire IIS is restarted.
- *SqlServer*. This is Session State is stored in a SQL Server storage. This is great because sessions survives after an IIS Application Pool or entire IIS restart, but it's a bottleneck as it means that every access to the session requires a deserialization and/or serialization of the Session State objects and, after all, database connections and so on.
- *StateServer*. Similar to *SqlServer*, but using a Session State Server provided by Microsoft. This mode isn't used at all, but it's an option... (I've no experience with it).
- *Custom*. You can implement some interfaces/abstract classes and define your own Session State storage.

In the other hand, Session State is server-side, it has nothing to do with cookies. It's a way of simulating state in a stateless world ruled by HTTP. Since ASP.NET writes an HTTP cookie in the browser, it can link a browser session with an unique server session too.

About if Session State is useful or not.... In my case, I've decided to avoid "states" at all. I prefer to stay stateless as much as possible. I write down some HTTP cookies in the browser to identity settings, preferences or users, and I do things per-request.

I prefer that because a good caching mechanism can insanely optimize the requests' performance as in most of the cases you wouldn't be accessing data directly in the store but in some cache, which means a lot of speed!

By the way, Session State shouldn't be used to store large object but basic values. Session State isn't a cache. For example, Session State could be a good place to store something like current logged-in user or his/her role. Or their profile identifier. Who knows.

Any other data should be queried in a per-request basis.

And again: cache should be your friend in terms of optimizing your environment and don't accessing the database or whatever in each request, compromising the system performance.

Comment: Fidemraizer, I appreciate it, I was really in need of clarification here. So, it seems that the Session variable isn't quite as unreliable as I thought. I guess it may be some other issue with it I am having, but I know that 'no matter what it is' it is assigned some string value, and then accessed almost immediately after on another page, and somehow mysteriously becomes null/empty for, seemingly, no reason. Nowhere in the code is it ever allowed to be empty or null before it is accessed.

Comment: Also, it is only on our server, and I think the default memory allowed for IIS before App_Pool recycling has very unlikely been reached, so shouldn't be that either, but who knows.

Comment: @VoidKing Yeah, actually InProc mode is very unreliable. Go for SqlServer mode if you want reliability. Since storing session values in SqlServer mode means that those must be serialized and deserialized but you need to retrieve them again, be careful about storing simple values: strings, integers, small objects, ... If you do so, you won't be very affected in terms of performance. For example, SharePoint cames with SqlServer mode by default and it works for large business.

Comment: Is there a way to switch these modes using WebMatrix (C#)? If so, how can this be done? This is the first I have ever heard of this, sry.

Comment: @VoidKing This is about configuring the `Web.config` file. Check this article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx